# Put text around a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, minipage, wrapfigure

I write a command to wrap text around tikz picture automatically (Image 1).
[image]

I want the linewidth can be expand when the text is higher than the image height (Image 2).
[image]

Please help correct below code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\newdimen\widthimmini
\newdimen\heightimmini
\newdimen\textimagewidth
\newbox\imbox
\newcommand{\putimage}[3][-12pt]{
        \setbox\imbox=\vbox{\hbox{#3}}
        \widthimmini=\wd\imbox
        \heightimmini=\ht\imbox 
        \textimagewidth=\dimexpr\linewidth - 1.075\widthimmini\relax
\par\vspace*{\dimexpr#1\relax}\noindent{\ignorespaces\begin{minipage}[t]{\textimagewidth}
    \vspace*{0pt}\ignorespaces
    \begingroup
    #2
    \endgroup
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\widthimmini}
    \vspace*{-1pt}
\begin{center}
    \begingroup
        #3
    \endgroup
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}
\putimage{ \lipsum[30]
}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle(2);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newpage
\putimage{ \lipsum[10]
}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle(2);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\noindent
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're making things needlessly complicated: the plain TeX `insbox` macro package can do what you want, and it works fine here. It defines an  `\InsertBoxR` command which takes two mandatory arguments: the number of lines unshortened before the box is inserted, and the box inserted, and one optional argument: the number of supplementary shortened lines, in case latex makes a wrong calculation of the necessary number of shortened lines to place the box.

There is also an `\InsertBoxL` and an `\InsertBoxC` commands.

Here is a possible code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{insbox.tex}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle(2);
\end{tikzpicture}}
 \lipsum[30]
\newpage

\InsertBoxR{3}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle(2);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\lipsum[10]
\noindent
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know the insbox.tex macro!

Comment: I compile success. Sometimes, the last line meets the figure or long distance. How can I fixe the problem. https://im.ge/i/Ozfgp

Comment: @NamTranLe: You can use the optional argument, which, contrary to LaTeX usual syntax, comes as the *last* argument. So, explicitly, I would use `\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{tikzpicture} … \end{tikzpicture}}[1]` for the first figure, and `[-1]` for the second figure.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I is wrong when there are two paragraphs wrapping the picture. How can I correct sir?

Comment: @NamTranLe: the situation is not quite  clear to me. What happens? The first has shortened lines, but not the second?